# gulp-autoprefixer problem using gulp, sass and css files not linking

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, sass, gulp

I'm a newbie looking for help with Gulp. (I read a few Stack Overflow posts and think this is about sourcemaps, but I don't know a lot about that)
Yesterday I installed Gulp and everything worked just fine. I'm using Sass for the first time and had the watch task on so it auto-refreshes and links but today it's not working, I tried to run it and this messsage appears:

```
'css' errored after 27 ms
CssSyntaxError in plugin "gulp-autoprefixer"
```

Can you help me out? I'm barely a beginner and don't know how to use the terminal.

Here is my gulpfile.js code:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

function css() {
    return gulp
        .src('scss/app.scss')
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            overrideBrowserslist : ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'expanded', // nested, compact,
        }))
        .pipe( gulp.dest('css') );

}

function watchFiles() {
    gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', css);
    gulp.watch('index.html');
}

// Registrar funciones como tareas // 
gulp.task( 'css', css );
gulp.task( 'watch', gulp.parallel( watchFiles ) );
```

My versions are these:
NODE - v12.18.3
NPM - 6.14.6
GULP - CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2

Comment: Are you sure your `dest` is right? Have you tried `gulp.dest('./css')`?

Comment: I'm sure :( But i tried it that way and the same error appears.